# Suppress duplicates of a group data which is in another group data in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Cystal Reports
scenario:

```
Group1 Location
Group2 Names
```

Group2 is below the Group1 in heirarichy.
I placed Group1 field location in Group2 names. I have seen duplicates of locations.

Sample data:

```
america  Tom
america  Jim
England  Peterson
England  Anderson
```

I want data as

```
america  Tom
         Jim
England  Peterson
         Anderson
```

Please provide solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the suppress duplicates option only works in the detail section. The simplest approach here would be to conditionally suppress the Group1 field with a condition like `{Table.Location} = Previous({Table.Location})` (assuming you have your fields in the group2 *header*).

EDIT: Since you have your fields in the Group2 *footer*, I suggest adding a new running total field, to be incremented on change of group2 and reset on change of group1, and conditionally suppress the Group1 field with a condition like `{NewRunningTotal} > 0`.

Comment: Hi Mark, i have kept fields in Group2 footer because i have running totals for Group2 and all these fields location, names and sum are placed in Group2 footer. I have written a condition as suggested by you but it is not working because currentfieldvalue and previous(object) gives same value(current value). Please let me know other solution

Comment: Hi Marks, please excuse me if i dont address your first name :). Thanks for your great solution,now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the correct group-name field in each group's group-header section, change group header one to 'underlay following section'.